# How do i know which Buttons are triggered to perform specific task in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have 2 buttons, one is called "Accept", which is used for updating of database while another is called "View", which is used for Redirecting. However, in GridView's SelectedIndexChanged, i wasnt able to Validate which buttons were click

so I have tried Using RowCommand for the "View" button and SelectedIndexChanged for "Accept" button. But RowCommand is triggering the "Accept" button in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="QgridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CssClass="table table-bordered" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
     ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" runat="server" 
     OnRowCommand="QgridView_RowCommand" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="QgridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No"> 
             <ItemTemplate>
               <span>
              <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
              </span>
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlField="coverimg" >
         <ControlStyle CssClass="coverimage"/>
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                                                
             </asp:ImageField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Buyer" DataField="buyer" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item" DataField="item" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price offered" DataField="price" />


         <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
           commandname="Accept"
           text="Accept"/>

         <asp:BoundField DataField="quoteid"  HeaderText="quoteid" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" >                                        
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>
          <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
         </asp:BoundField>

     <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol">
      <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>
      <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>

   <asp:BoundField DataField="rtype" HeaderText="rtype" ItemStyle- 
      CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle- CssClass="hiddencol">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="seller" HeaderText="seller" ItemStyle- 
        CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>
         <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>


      <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
        commandname="View"
       text="View"/>



    </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>

  // Behind COde page
  protected void QgridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = QgridView.SelectedRow;
        string seller = row.Cells[10].Text;
        string item = row.Cells[4].Text;
        string type = row.Cells[9].Text;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Text);
        int quoteid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Text);
        productDAO productdao = new productDAO();
        productdao.GridPush(quoteid, id)

    }

    protected void QgridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "View")
        {
            Response.Redirect("ListingItems.aspx");

        }          
    }
```

I want the "Accept" BUtton to perform the updating of database while the "View button to perform Response.Redirect. However, RowCommand does not fire and instead, it triggers the "Accept" button in SelectedIndexChanged. May i know how can perform the different task for each button?

[Gettting row data from GridView]

```
   protected void QgridView_RowCommand(object sender, 
   GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onrowcommand");

        if (e.CommandName == "View")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ButtonView is clicked");
            Response.Redirect("ListingItems.aspx");

        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("buttonAccept is clicked");
            productDAO productdao = new productDAO();
            //GridViewRow row = QgridView.SelectedRow;

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = QgridView.Rows[index];

            string id = row.Cells[8].Text; //Returns me nothing
        }

        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("no command name");
        }


    }
```

Comment: on row command you can check command name easily and perform the operation accordingly!

Comment: so SelectedIndex changed is not needed in this case right? Use Rowcommand is enough to perform the needed individual task for each button?

Comment: yes correct. if you can do on row command by identifying the button command then why need to go for index change or other events.

Comment: @UsmanMirza hi thank you so much. And mind me if i ask another question. Now i have switched to using ButtonField. The problem im facing now is that i cant get the row data from the Gridview. I have added the codes above, u can take  a look at it. i cant seems to get the row data as it always return no value.

Comment: @UsmanMirza i tried using 

int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
 GridViewRow row = QgridView.Rows[index];

as shown in the documentation as well as several solutions online but i cant seems to solve it as well.

Comment: get row of gridview in this way GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer); and then try and if still you are not getting value then i will recommend put a label with visible false in item template and get the control like: Label MyLabelValue = row.FindControl("MyLabelVal") as Label;

Comment: @UsmanMirza alright, let me try

Comment: @UsmanMirza Hi im currently trying your suggestions but i wasnt successful. I posted another questions, hope you could take a look at what's wrong. I made a few changes. I have been searching for solutions but none helped me.

Comment: @UsmanMirza https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547889/how-can-i-get-row-labels-data-from-gridview-in-rowcommand

Answer (score 0):

I think you are no need to check the rowcommand or onselected Index change event you can directly set button on click event. if you are using the  inside your Gridview, then you should be able to register an event in your button code as:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="YourclickEvent" />
```

For more details on event you should read this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50540/GridView-Event-Handling

One Addition: if using row command then identify each button with command name and you can perform your task easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code `SelectedIndexChanged` should be never fired (no `select` command).
`RowCommand` handler always fire first (before more specific handlers).
Look at sample working code.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="CategoryID" 
    DataSourceID="sqlCategory" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category Name" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Accept" HeaderText="Accept" ShowHeader="True" Text="Accept" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="View" HeaderText="View" ShowHeader="True" Text="View" />
        <%-- Use HyperLinkField instead of ButtonField --%>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CategoryID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="category.aspx?categoryid={0}" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataTextFormatString="View {0}" HeaderText="Direct View" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<%-- Data from NorthWind learning DB --%>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlCategory" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories" 
    UpdateCommand="update categories set categoryName=@CategoryName where CategoryID=@CategoryID">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Trace.Write("GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged");// fired by "select" command after RowCommand finished 
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.Write("GridView1_RowCommand");
    //
    if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
    {
        var categoryId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value;//e.CommandArgument is display index
        Trace.Write(e.CommandName + ": " + e.CommandArgument + " : " + categoryId.ToString());
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "View")
    {
        Trace.Write("View " + e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```